# Get back data from window popup child page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I open a login page in a new window using the following code:
`const newWindow = window.open (url, ...)`

After the user authorizes my application, the third-party app they used for logging in redirects them back to one of my pages with specific parameters in the URL.
In the callback (window popup) I extracted those parameters.

Now, how to retrieve these parameters back on the main page?

I tried to do it with Redux. On the login page, I updated the state of an item with the parameters I received from the callback. I checked, and it worked but when i close the login page window, the store of the main page means to lose the changes.

Comment: from what I understand, you might want to use local storage or session storage as a medium for storing the url parameters that you want.. when the page was redirected, the url parameters on that area only affects that page, not the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using local storage. Thanks @catzilla

On the callback page, I stored the API response (including access token, refresh token, expiration date, etc.) after stringified it:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
```

After closing the Callback window, I implemented a check in the main window to detect when the child (callback) window is closed:

```
const checkWindowClosed = (childWindow, setWindowIsOpen) => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (childWindow.closed) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            setWindowIsOpen(false) // useState
        }
    }, 500); //every 500ms
}
```

Then, I retrieve and parse data from local storage using the same key :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!windowIsOpen) {
        const value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))
        //
    }
}, [windowIsOpen]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).